# TortoiseSVN Error: Could not send request body: an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: iis, iis-7, tortoisesvn

Let me preface this by saying I have basically 0 knowledge of web development. That being said, I'll still try to provide you with as much information as I possibly can. Our client is using IIS7 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine. The TortoiseSVN error they're getting is this:

> Error: Could not send request body: an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Using the powers of Google, it seems that there's two possible things that could be occurring here. As it is a 4GB file, I've seen people mention that it could be a configuration issue in that the timeout could be a little short, that I might need to enable a setting somewhere to allow committing of larger files or that it could be a network issue. It might be useful to note that they can commit smaller files.

I've all ready tried disabling the firewall, as well as the antivirus, on the server and having them retry, but that didn't work. They are trying to upload from a desktop to the server and they are on the same network through a gigabit switch. I'm sure I'm missing useful information for you guys but I'm a total noob to web dev, their set up, and actually understanding what they're trying to do. If you need any more information from me I'll be glad to provide it.

Comment: I recently got this error, I suspect that it came with a Windows Update. I have Windows 7 64bit. Cannot update my working copy since then.

Comment: I have this problem with all my repositories. I cannot update anything anymore. :-(

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be the too strict timeout options configured in Apache2's reqtimeout module. I simply disabled it

```
a2dismod reqtimeout
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Chocolate to: https://serverfault.com/questions/297562/svn-https-problem-could-not-read-status-line-connection-was-closed-by-ser